# Historical manhwa in which the female lead has been reincarnated multiple times and attends the school she founded in her past life

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

I read this manhwa a while ago.

The female lead with white hair has been reincarnated multiple times. In her most recent life, she’s reincarnated as as a noble and attends the school she founded in her past life. She also just wants a peaceful life.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you be more specific about when (what year) you read this?  Do you remember where you found it?

Answer (score 1):

Is this ***[The Lady Needs a Break](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-lady-needs-a-break)***...?

> It is my cursed destiny to be reborn endlessly. A king, an archmage, a slave, a saint, a witch... I’ve done it all in my thousand years of life, and frankly, I need a break! My goal now is simple: to live like an absolute sloth. Unfortunately, I am Rubia, the daughter of a grand duke with a demanding family and a fiancé to boot. To live my dream sloth life, I’m running away from it all... except no matter where I go, nobody will leave me be! I just want to nap, but being lazy is hard work!

As noted in the synopsis above, the protagonist has been reborn multiple times and lived various different lives over a thousand-year period.

In her 54th life, she's reborn as [Rubia de Grandia La Luxen](https://www.anime-planet.com/characters/rubia-de-grandia-la-luxen), the 18-year-old, white-haired daughter of a grand duke. On the same day that she reincarnates, she decides to leave home in order to escape her cruel stepmother, whom her neglectful father allows to mistreat her.

Not long after, in chapter 7, she enrols at the Linette Academy, which started out as a small school founded by one of her previous incarnations 200 years prior.

> [image: "The Lady Needs a Break," chapter 6, page 2.] [image: "The Lady Needs a Break," chapter 7, page 8.]

You can read the full manhwa at [Tapas](https://tapas.io/series/the-lady-needs-a-break/info).